# How to use union query on the same table and sum (value) in mysql?

Tags: mysql, union

I have a table :

```
OC  Period(MM/YYYY) Ing
CHO 04/01/2016      100
CHO 04/01/2016      200
CHO 04/01/2016      0
CFE 04/01/2016      400
CFE 04/01/2016      350
CFE 04/01/2016      0
```

I have an SQL query like this:

```
  (SELECT OC,Ing FROM contacts c where ing > 0)
  UNION ALL
  (SELECT OC,Sum(Ing) FROM contacts c where ing = 0 Group by OC)
```

I want to get a result like this:

```
Ref Period(MM/YYYY) Ing
CHO 04/01/2016      100
CHO 04/01/2016      200
CHO 04/01/2016      300
CFE 04/01/2016      400
CFE 04/01/2016      350
CFE 04/01/2016      750
```

Comment: are you sure your desired output is correct?

Comment: Thanks .But i want to get a result : Sum(Ing) with group by OC

Comment: My bet, I forgot a condition in query

Comment: Delete `where ing = 0` in the second select.

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT c.OC, c.Period, c.Ing FROM contacts c where c.ing > 0)
UNION ALL
(SELECT c.OC, c.Period, Sum(c.Ing) AS Ing FROM contacts c Group by c.OC, c.Period)
```

You could wrap it in another `select from` statement if you need to sort the output